# mongodb - two depend aggregations for the same document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose the following collection is given:

```
{"Year" : 2014, "State" : "AZ", "Distributer" : "AAA", "Revenu_category_A" : 300, "Revenu_category_B" : 42, "Revenu_category_C" : 75}
{"Year" : 2015, "State" : "AZ","Distributer" : "AAA","Revenu_category_A" : 475, "Revenu_category_B" : 78, "Revenu_category_C" : 21}
{ "Year" : 2014, "State" : "NY","Distributer" : "AAA","Revenu_category_A" : 74, "Revenu_category_B" : 44, "Revenu_category_C" : 13}
{"Year" : 2015, "State" : "NY","Distributer" : "BBB","Revenu_category_A" : 234, "Revenu_category_B" : 41, "Revenu_category_C" : 433}
```

For each of the above distributors I want to find the category that contributes the least amount of revenue and the state where the distributor gets the most amount of revenue from that category during all the years.

For example in reference to the data above. If we look at distributor `AAA` and calculate the total revenue for each category. The result will be as follow:

The total revenue of `category A` will be: 849
The total revenue of `category B` will be: 164
The total revenue of `category C` will be: 109

According to that results, `category C` has the lowest contribution to the total revenue of distributor `AAA` (Total revenue of 109).

Then we need to find the state where `category C` produce the most revenue for distributor `AAA`. That state is `AZ` which produce total revenue of 96, in compare to NY that produce only 13 for that category.

So the expected result can be show as follow:

```
{"Distributer" : "AAA", "Least_Revenue_category": "Revenu_category_A", "State_with_most_revenue" : "AZ"}
{"Distributer" : "BBB"...}...
```

Comment: can you add expected result from that documents in your question.

Comment: In order to make the problem much more clearer, I edited it and added an example with an expected result.

Comment: the category A to C fields will be dynamic or always fixed?

Comment: Can be dynamic, but for the simplicity it can be fixed

Comment: In other words, for the sake of simplicity, we will see the categories as three fixed categories

Comment: In the real data, how do you tell a revenue category field from the other fields like `Year`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that with aggregation, you will need a way to identify which fields are the revenue categories.  The pipeline stages might be:

- gather the revenue category fields into an array of key-value pairs
- unwind the array
- group by distributer, state, and category, and sum the revenue per category
- sort by revenue descending
- group by distributer and category, store the first record (max by state) and sum the revenue per category
- sort by revenue ascending
- group by distributer capturing the first record for each distributer.  This will be the least category and the highest state within that category for that distributer.

If a regular expression match can identify these fields this could look like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {
      fields: {
        $filter: {
          input: {$objectToArray: "$$ROOT"},
          cond: {
            "$regexMatch": {
              "input": "$$this.k",
              "regex": "^Revenu"
            }
          }
        }
      }
   }},
  {$unwind: "$fields"},
  {$group: {
      _id: {
        distributer: "$Distributer",
        state: "$State",
        category: "$fields.k"
      },
      stateTotal: {$sum: "$fields.v"}
  }},
  {$sort: {stateTotal: -1}},
  {$group: {
      _id: {
        distributer: "$_id.distributer",
        category: "$_id.category"
      },
      most: {
        $first: {
          state: "$_id.state",
          stateTotal: "$stateTotal"
        }
      },
      catTotal: {$sum: "$stateTotal"}
  }},
  {$sort: {catTotal: 1}},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$_id.distributer",
      "Least_Revenue_category": {$first: "$_id.category"},
      "State_with_most_revenue": {$first: "$most.state"}
  }},
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      Distributer: "$_id",
      "Least_Revenue_category": 1,
      "State_with_most_revenue": 1
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0fu3GT21oB1)

Comment: It is very beautiful and it gives the solution. What if the categories were fixed? What would the solution look like without using regex?

Comment: All you need is some boolean expression in the `cond` that will return true for the field names that you want to treat as categories and false for any others.  That could be any of `$eq`, `$in`, `$or`, `$not`, `$regex`, etc. Nearly any of the logical query operators could be used there.